# Checkboxes selectable but not able to uncheck

Tags: .net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with check boxes.
What would cause the checkboxes to be selectable but not able to uncheck in .Net 4.0, but checkable and unchekable in .Net 2.0?

Comment: "not able to uncheck in .Net 4.0, but uncheckable in .Net 2.0?"  If I'm reading this right, you just said they aren't uncheckable in both frameworks.  Did you mistype?

Comment: 4.0: can select but not uncheck checked checkbox. 2.0: can uncheck checked checkbox.

Comment: @Inuyasha It was a typo :(. Sorry.

Comment: Can you post any code that shows the problem?

Comment: The code doesn't show the problem. But when I run my program, in .Net 4.0, the checkboxes are shown, I can select them but I cannot uncheck them.

Comment: I can't reproduce it.  Code needed.  We need a short, working example exhibiting the problem.

Comment: @Davide: Why are you assuming this is ASP.NET/WebForms?

Comment: correct, sorry my mistake, I saw DataGridView and that about ASP.NET GridView... fixing this! Thanks!

Comment: Are they set as readonly?  Or is there an event that is causing them to re-check.  We need to see a code example.

Comment: Right click and view source, then paste results.

Comment: @MatteKarla Inuyasha, Kev Ritchie, Richard Friend. I wasn't asking for a solution, although I am very grateful. I was simply thinking if there is a method about the checkboxes which works differently for diferent .Net versions. However, I solved it - the problem was the width of the checkboxes. It was 18 and it worked ok for .Net 2.0, but not fo .Net 4.0. If it's 20, it works for both :) I'll answer my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the width of the checkboxes. It was 18 and it worked ok for .Net 2.0, but not fo .Net 4.0. If it's 20, it works for both.